# Conflicts with variants in installed packages

Tags: openmpi, spack

With spack, I am trying to install a package using a previous install of `openmpi@3.1.5`.
And I get the following error during concretization:

> Error: trying to set variant "wrapper-rpath" in package "openmpi", but the package has no such variant [happened during concretization ... ]

Indeed if I do a `spack info openmpi` there is no `wrapper-rpath` but a `runpath` variant instead.

Therefore, I manually changed the `spack-db/index.json` to put runpath instead of wrapper-rpath in the openmpi variants. The concretization is therefore succesfull but during installation I hit the following :

> Error: Specs openmpi@3.1.5%gcc@7.3.1 ... +runpath + ... and openmpi@3.1.5%gcc@7.3.1 ... + wrapper-rpath + ... have the same SHA-1 prefix!

So my understanding is that the change of variant name results in a new SHA1, and I should change this SHA1 everywhere.

First, am I right that the name of the variant has been changed? Second, is there a simple way to update the database accordingly and keep using the already installed package ?

With thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> First, am I right that the name of the variant has been changed?

Yes, the variant name was changed in https://github.com/spack/spack/pull/17073

> Second, is there a simple way to update the database accordingly and keep using the already installed package?

Unfortunately not. You can either rebuild `openmpi`, or you can explicitly link to it using its hash. See `spack find -l openmpi` to find the hash. Then use it like `spack install foo ^/hashofopenmpi`.